# React Native debugging error

Tags: react-native

[image]

As you see,when I open dev tool in chrome,It will soon turn into this red screen.If I do not open dev mode,it works, and `console.log` can log infomations in Xcode console.(this way is not use Xcode)

Comment: If I'm not go to debug, the app will run normally.what's the problems?

Answer (score 0):

just open localhost:8081/debugger-ui and press Cmd+R in simulator, or dismiss this error, open developer menu in App and disable "Debug in Chrome" option

Answer (score 0):

try to update your react-native version to more stable version may be 0.35 or 0.38.
this basically happens when react-native is not able to load the bundles into developer tool.